# What is that airport equipment that looks like an SMR but rotates like a windmill?

Tags: airport, feature-identification, radar

[image: equipment that looks like an SMR but on its side]
— [YouTube](https://youtu.be/zzXnGw2fOdo?t=1177)

The one rotating horizontally looks like a standard Surface Movement Radar (SMR). But the one next it, **rotating vertically** (like a windmill or wind turbine), what is that? Wouldn't that be scanning a vertical slice? It also [doesn't look like a PAR](https://www.google.com/search?q=Precision%20Approach%20Radar&tbm=isch), which has a vertically scanning component.

The example shown here is seen at Amsterdam Airport Schiphol (EHAM). I failed to find the right keywords to find anything about it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That is a **bird tracking radar antenna** to detect and track birds in the vicinity of the airport. The vertical component is used to determine the bird's altitude.

> [image: ROBIN's 3D Flex]
>
> ROBIN's 3D Flex system consists of a horizontal S-band radar, combined with a flexible Frequency Modulated Continuous Wave (FMCW) radar. The horizontal S-band radar identifies the presence and number of birds in time – including their location, height, direction, speed and route – up to 10 kilometres away, all around, day and night.
>
> The FMCW radar has three modes:
>
> - 'Scanning' mode, by which 3D information is retrieved for all desired directions.
> - 'Staring' mode, in which the radar points in one direction to identify targets up to 6 km away.
> - 'Automatic Acquisition' mode, where the vertical X-Band radar slews in azimuth to the cue of the horizontal S-Band radar, based on the objects with highest RCS. In this way much of the bird tracks (in all directions) will be assigned elevation data.

<sup>([Robin Radar Systems - 3D Flex Radar System - Bird Strike Prevention in 3D](https://www.robinradar.com/3d-flex-radar-system-360-degrees))</sup>

Apparently, Amsterdam Schiphol was the first airport to be equipped with such a radar system [in 2013](https://www.robinradar.com/full-bird-radar-coverage-at-schiphol-airport) due to a large number of geese in the vicinity:

> Schiphol first deployed a single bird radar (Robin 3D Flex) at
> the ‘Polderbaan’, one of it’s six runways. After successful
> testing Schiphol acquired four more 3D Flex radars to cover the
> entire airport.
>
> Robin Radar Systems’ 3D Flex radars detect and track birds in
> and a round the airport up to 6-8km away. They also provide the
> height information of the birds. Each bird controller receives
> the radar data on an iPad in their vehicles.
>
> [image: Robin 3D Flex at Schiphol]

<sup>([Robin Radar Systems - Schiphol Case Study](https://www.robinradar.com/hubfs/RobinRadarSystems_January2020/Docs/schiphol-case-study-final-v1-7.pdf?hsLang=en))</sup>

Comment: Now I'm just imagining ATC being somehow in contact with those birds - "Canadian Goose CG103, you are cleared for landing in the field to the east of runway 6..."

Comment: CG103, you are deviating from your assigned vector. Please return to designated airways or you _will_ be shot down.

Comment: Is it possible the vertical antenna does scan a slice and is aimed along the runways? The first quotation is not really clear (not your fault!), as it also says the horizontal one scans heights. Great find btw.

Comment: @ymb1 "the vertical X-Band radar slews in azimuth to the cue of the horizontal S-Band radar, based on the objects with highest RCS" -> that sounds like it is only scanning a slice, but not necessarily along the runway since it can slew in azimuth. I agree though that the description is not very good (sounds like something the marketing department wrote). E.g. in the paragraph before they claim that the horizontal S-band radar can also measure height, which does not make sense.